# What is a good replacement for the obsolete XmlValidatingReader class?

Tags: c#, validation

When I try to create an application with C# these method gave warning to me

```
        //get validator
        XmlValidatingReader xmlValidator = new XmlValidatingReader(new FileStream(xmlfile,FileMode.Open), XmlNodeType.Document,psContext);
```

and

```
        //compile to load schema elements
        schema.Compile(new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallback));
```

I use VS 2008 with .NET Framework 3.5 to implemented this.

Please give me the correct way to do this.

Comment: It tells you: `Use XmlReader created by XmlReader.Create() method using appropriate XmlReaderSettings instead.`

Answer (score 1):

To validate your XML documents against an XSD schema, use [System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaset.aspx)